# Batch "for" command to extract columns from TSV file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i'm stuck on a .bat with this line of code, trying to extract specific columns from a file where each entry is delimited by `tab` character

```
setlocal
(for /f "tokens= 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 21, 22, 24, 29, 32, 37, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 53, 54, 55 delims=   " %%a in (%TNP%\TEST1.tsv) do echo %%a  %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g %%h %%i %%j %%k %%l %%m %%n %%o %%p %%q %%r %%s %%t %%u %%v %%w %%x %%y %%z) > %TNP%\TEST.txt
endlocal
```

The code works until it reaches `%%q` from then on it keeps printing %q %r %s etc etc on the output file, though the columns i've chosen are present in the input file

Comment: There is a 31 Token limit with the `FOR /F`.  See [this](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/clevertricks.php#FORListExtended)

Comment: You might very well need a more powerful language like powershell or the windows scripting host.

Comment: yup, thought i could do it in bat, i was completely unaware of such petty limitation. Thanks guys

Comment: @MrVenom, if you read my link there is a work around for that.  You can get up to 65 tokens if you nest multiple `FOR /F` commands.

Comment: @Squashman
i did read it, trying it now, thanks a lot, that's a very helpful article